# Mocking static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I want to mock static method which is called within other static method.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void methodA(String s)
    {
        ...
        methodB(s);
        ...
    }
    public static void methodB(String s)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, I want to mock `methodA`, but I want to skip calling `methodB`.
I tried almost all solutions that I was able to find, without any success. Every time `methodB` is called.

Some solutions that I used:

```
PowerMockito.suppress(method(MyClass.class, "methodB"));
MyClass.methodA("s");
```

_

```
PowerMockito.stub(method(MyClass.class, "methodB"));
MyClass.methodA("s");
```

_

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
doNothing().when(MyClass.class, "methodB", anyString());
MyClass.methodA("s");
```

And many others...
Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do that? If you want to test your `methodA` and it calls the other method, maybe you should also test it that way AND test your `methodB`.

Comment: methodB works with specific device, so I am not able to mock that part, so I want to skip it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but instead of NOT calling `methodB`, why don´t you just mock the method?

Comment: The nice thing about the accepted answer: Spies work with **pure** Mockito. Gets you **off** the PowerMock(ito) train, which is normally a good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you should Spy your class instead of mocking it.

In that situation all the static methods will be called with real implementation and on top of that you could instruct to not call `methodB`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
class MyClassTest
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
       PowerMockito.spy(MyClass.class);
       doNothing().when(MyClass.class, "methodB", anyString());
       MyClass.methodA("s");
    }
}
```

I have written an article on [Mocking Static Methods](https://www.sourceartists.com/blog/legacy-code/mocking-static-methods-with-powermock/27) if you need a further read.